# Can I use PWM to control the speeds of more than two motors separately in ATmega32A?

Tags: pwm, avr

Can I use PWM to control the speeds of  more than two motors  separately in ATmega32A ?

The latest thing I could do is controlling The speeds of two mototrs using fast PWM  mode in counter 1 with two compare values OCR1A & OCR1B.

Comment: What frequency are we talking about here? You could use counter 0 or 2 if 8 bits are enough?

Comment: 50 to 100 Hz for a 9 volt DC motor .. do you have any helpful codes or articles ?

Comment: It's kinda hard to give some example without more information. Are the other timers in use  (what does the atmega besides driving pwm), are the 2 PWM signals correlated to eachother?  You should also add your existing code for driving Timer 1